# How to update a chart in Word dynamically with a form

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, charts, forms, microsoft-word-365

I have a dynamic chart inside a word document.
I inserted an Excel workbook via the Insert -> Tables -> Excel (not sure about the exact english text) rather than just inserting a chart.

[image]

My problem is, that to edit the data for this chart, I have to double click the chart. It's then opened in Excel, within word, where I can change the values.
I want to make it a standard word form, where you simply enter the values in a form control text field.
I cannot however figure out **how to link this data to the excel object**.
When the document is limited to function as a form, the excel object is locked, which is a problem.

Comment: One idea would be to switch entire form to Content Controls rather than legacy form fields. Use a different Restrict Editing option than Filling in Forms. There are free utilities to change legacy form fields to Content Controls.

Comment: You could improve your question by adding a view link to a document with the problem saved on OneDrive or DropBox.

Comment: I could, but all I'm asking is, how to change the excel value without opening the excel part. If you can, but I assume it's possible.

Comment: I do not assume that it is possible since the values are stored in the Excel part.